# invalid activator

Tags: eclipse

I know there are other questions on the subject but I' ve tried them all and didn' t work for me. I want to write some output to excel files from my rcp plug in but it shows:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook
```

So I do: `plugin.xml->runtime tab-> add the poi jars in the classpath section`.

But then when i try to run, it shows:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator spyros.getInfo.Activator for 
bundle spyros.getInfo is invalid.
```

My questions:

1. Do i have to put the poi jars in a specific folder (example in META-INF folder) and then add them to classpath?
2. How can i fix the activator error?

My MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: GetInfo
Bundle-SymbolicName: spyros.getInfo; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: spyros.getInfo.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.7.1",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.7.100",
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui;bundle-version="3.7.1"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: org.apache.commons.collections
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/poi-3.8-20120326.jar,
 lib/poi-examples-3.8-20120326.jar,
 lib/poi-excelant-3.8-20120326.jar,
 lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar,
 lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar,
 lib/poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar
```

My build properties

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               icons/,\
               lib/poi-3.8-20120326.jar,\
               lib/poi-examples-3.8-20120326.jar,\
               lib/poi-excelant-3.8-20120326.jar,\
               lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar,\
               lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar,\
               lib/poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar
```

My plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="spyros.getInfo.handlers.GetInfo"
            id="spyros.getInfo.commands.GetInfo"
            name="GetInfo">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="spyros.getInfo.commands.GetInfo"
               label="My Info">
            <command
                  commandId="spyros.getInfo.commands.GetInfo"
                  label="Get Info"
                  style="push"
                  tooltip="Get Info from methods">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

I am so confused, but i am sure that stackoverflow community will help, because you are the best! Thanx in advance!

Comment: solved it! i found the solution here: http://blog.chris-alex-thomas.com/2007/07/17/eclipse-activator-class-is-invalid/comment-page-1/#comment-19889

Answer (score 1):

This is because of:

> There has been a ClassNotFoundException trying to load the class in the first place, before it's even got to the start() method.

So for solve this problem:

1. You have to add `.` in to your class path see following image.

   [image]
2. Add scr as source in your build and `.` in your `bin.includes`. See the image below:

   [image]